# SSIS Ole Db Select IN w/ Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Would like to do a select like:

> Select * from Table1 a WHERE a.ItemName IN (?)

Where ? is a list of strings that could be equal to a.ItemName I plan on using ? as a string variable set by a script task that reads a file.

The variable is User::IncludeQuery= 'item1','item2','item3'

Which is set by the script task via

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var item in includeList)
        sb.Append("'"+item + "'" + "," );
  Variables.IncludeQuery = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

But I believe that the parameterization will occur and make my variable into a string like

```
   ''''item1''','''item2''','''item3''''
```

and escape my quotes

Comment: An alternative is to build the entire SQL statement in a var, and then execute that.

Comment: @destination-data Thanks, that works forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An alternative is to build the entire SQL statement in a var, and then
>   execute that.

Words by a wise man